# How do I make my site look good at any size and resolution?

Tags: html, css

I've read a lot about this thing. Most of users suggest media queries, but I would like to know is there any specific 100% working way that allows your site to look great(elements doesn't lose they positions) even on another resolutions/browsers with just html/css. If not, what to do then?(get back to media queries?)

I don't know much about css/html, but when I tried to open my page with another pc or phone, it looked awful - (page which i designed for my PC's resolution).
I also tried 'em', '%', 'min-width' and 'min-height' but didn't go so good.

Sorry because I ask this, even there is probably an solution out there. I just wanted clear and straight answer so I don't lose my track and get confused even more.

Thanks

Comment: Media queries ARE a 100% working way to make your site look great. That being said, there are frameworks that help you build your site in such a way that it looks nice. For eg. bootstrap

Comment: Media queries are the de facto way of [responsive web design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is going to be using bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/). This is some free open source css code that simplifies a lot of things, including what you're trying to do

EDIT: As others have said, media queries are the most common and potentially best way. Bootstrap is just a simple way of getting your site to look good on most screen sizes.

Comment: Bootstrap uses Media Queries.

Comment: @Kody I'm aware, however bootstrap is a simplified way to use them.

Comment: I am glad that I finally got some directions. Will try them all, but will start with "Media Queries" first. 

You helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Media queries are the best thing to use when it comes to fluid web design. Think of media queries as custom presets you can create for each or a range of screen sizes. It is the best way to inject fluid design into your website.

Comment: Well said. Note that doing the media queries yourself will be very time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Responsive Web Design revolves around [Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/). It's the ability to define certain **resolutions** to force the page to display in a specific way for that resolution. This is how a single web page can be rendered to look native to a phone, tablet, and/or PC without having to create 3 different web pages/applications.

Ideally, you wouldn't want to write this yourself. I'd recommend one of the following libraries, then build on these libraries to fit your need:

- [Material Design (Google Design)](http://www.getmdl.io/)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Now, if you don't want to use a library or media queries, maybe [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) will help. I don't recommend not using a library, nor not using media queries though.

Comment: Very clear and descriptive answer.You helped a lot and I will try them for sure. Hope I will fit to them(otherwise they will need to make Media Queries for me hehehehe ^^ ).